# RSpec: How can I stub a method on an object, before instantiation, without having to stub all the rest?

Tags: rspec, rubygems, mocking

I am writing a gem for Rails, which includes a generator to create a model. Under certain circumstances, the generator is supposed to call itself, and it uses the `generate` method to do this. This works fine when actually using it.

I am using RSpec 3.2 with `generator_spec` to try and test this functionality, but being a gem, when it gets to the `generate` call, it complains that Rails doesn't exist:

```
/path/to/ruby: No such file or directory -- bin/rails (LoadError)
```

So I have been trying to stub the `Generator#generate` method to make it do the same thing as `run_generator` in the spec, immediately before the `run_generator` calls that call `generate` in the middle of them.
However, for all of my potential solutions, I have run into problems.

#### Outright overriding the class - can't use the spec method.

```
class Generator
  def generate(*args)
    run_generator args[1..-1]
  end
end
```

This raises `undefined method 'run_generator'`. Not surprising.

#### Using a partial double - instantiated too late.

```
allow(generator).to receive(:generate) { |*args| run_generator args[1..-1] }
```

This would be perfect, but `run_generator` calls a *class* method behind the scenes, so the `generator` in question doesn't exist yet.

#### Using an instance double - disallows other methods.

```
recursible = instance_double(Generator)
allow(recursible).to receive(:generate) { |*args| run_generator args[1..-1] }
test_case_instance.generator_class = recursible
```

However, using a double requires you to stub *all* the methods on it that are going to be used - and all the rest would simply be calling their original implementations. That seems difficult and unnecessary. Is there any way to get round it?

Comment: have you tried: `allow_any_instance_of(Generator).to receive(:generate) ...`

Comment: @TarynEast promising! but now I'm getting `rspec __generate_without_any_instance__ takes -2 argument, but it should not.`

Comment: ok, so stubs are expected to paper over a method entirely and replace it with simple return-values... when you pass the correct arguments... which means you do need to actually pass arguments to it (in this case i just abstracte dover that with the `...` but you should have something like `.with(arg1, arg2)` (whatever your expected arguments are to be) and then you should return a return value... However... if you are actually trying to run code in the stub... then you're probably using it for the wrong purpose.. and there's probably another way you should be doing this.

Comment: have you googled for tutorials on how to test gems that are rails gems? I think they tend to include full mini-apps in the test directory...

Comment: I have a feeling that `run_generator` actually _calls_ `generate` somewhere along the chain, somehow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Taryn East](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219883/taryn-east) ended up giving me the [vital clue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908249/rspec-how-can-i-stub-a-method-on-an-object-before-instantiation-without-havin/29910330#comment47939774_29908249): I needed a full-blown Rails app in my test directory.

Unfortunately, `generator_spec`'s `prepare_destination` method completely blows the target directory away, so here's what I ended up with:

```
it 'the test' do
  system "rails new #{destination_root} -Bfq" # no bundling, force overwrite, quiet
  File.write "#{destination_root}/Gemfile", "gem '#{File.basename Dir.pwd}', path: '#{Dir.pwd}'", mode: 'a'
  system "cd #{destination_root} && bundle install --quiet"

  # ... continue with the test as before
```